Google Libre Code128 - Html. Encoded Char not rendering properly
I have an HTML document that includes this line of text:
<div style="margin:5px"><span style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 128'; font-size: 30px;">Ì1234560Î</span></div>
This is code128 encoded string being passed to the Libre Barcode 128 font which is installed and linked in the html.
However it is rendering in the HTML Displayed file as:
�1234560�
I have the HTML encoded to UTF-8, but that doesn't seem to be working.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Have you verified in the browser debugger which font is being used for the text?  It could be a font availability or naming issue.

Try adding cursive to your font-family declaration:
<div style="margin:5px"><span style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 128', cursive; font-size: 30px;">Ì1234560Î</span></div>



  var x = '123456';
  var j, intWeight, intLength, intWtProd = 0, arrayData = [];
  var arraySubst = [ "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "Æ", "Ç", "È", "É", "Ê" ];
/*
 * Checksum Calculation for Code 128 B
 */
  intLength = x.length;
  arrayData[0] = 104;
  intWtProd = 104;
  for (j = 0; j < intLength; j += 1) {
    arrayData[j + 1] = x.charCodeAt(j) - 32; // Have to convert to Code 128 encoding
    intWeight = j + 1; // to generate the checksum
    intWtProd += intWeight * arrayData[j + 1]; // Just a weighted sum
  }
  arrayData[j + 1] = intWtProd % 103; // Modulo 103 on weighted sum
  arrayData[j + 2] = 106; // Code 128 Stop character
  chr = parseInt(arrayData[j + 1], 10); // Gotta convert from character to a number
  if (chr > 94) {
    chrString = arraySubst[chr - 95];
  } else {
    chrString = String.fromCharCode(chr + 32);
  }
  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = 'Chksum (' + chr + '), char (' + chrString + ') for text = "' + x + '"';
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Ì' + x + chrString + 'Î';
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+128" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="check"></div>
  <br />
  <span id="test"
        style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 128', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;"> </span><br />
</body>



